# Why does pip install biopython fail (but other packages succeed)?

Tags: python, pip, biopython

I am trying to install python packages in a directory shared by a group of developers.   We do not have sudo permission.   This works for some packages (e.g. seqmagick), but not for others(e.g. biopython).  Can anyone tell me what is different about those that fail. and is there any workaround?

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

I have created a setup.cfg file like this in the current directory,

```
[install]
install-base=/tmp/group/python
install-purelib=$base/lib
install-platlib=$base/lib.$PLAT
install-scripts=/tmp/different/bin
install-headers=$base/include
install-data=$base/data
```

The following works, and everything ends up in the right place:

> $ pip install --no-deps seqmagick

But this does not,

> $ pip install --no-deps biopython

The failure is,

```
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BioSQL
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BioSQL': Permission denied
```

Why would pip (or setup.py?) be installing stuff in /usr/local when the setup.cfg scheme points elsewhere?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: This is one of the major design cases for the tool [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) which makes user installation of packages to non-system-wide locations easy and simple. The use of `--no-deps` in pip seems inadvisable because pip is a package-manager and you are defeating one of the main features of package management; this will almost guarantee the installed package won't work if it has dependencies. Use virtualenv if you can.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I added `--no-deps` to avoid confusing the issue with a long list of dependencies getting installed.  I wanted to narrow the question down to just two packages - one of which respects setup.cfg and another that does not.  After poking around at this for a while, it seems that the only reliable way to install packages (including wheels) in a non-standard location, without using a virtualenv, is with `--user` and `PYTHONUSERBASE`.  Unfortunately then you don't get to split out scripts into a different location.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely due to you having an extremely old version of pip, try this first:

```
pip install pip --upgrade
```

Cross reference https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1307#issuecomment-340407171